# How to Initial android Exoplayer play and pause buttons with custom UI?

Tags: android-studio, exoplayer2.x

I'm using Exoplayer 2.17.1 and want to customize UI. Everything works OK but it can not Initialize the play and pause buttons as you can see in the photo and show both of them and it doesn't work.

[image]

In fragment_home.xml:

```
  <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView
                android:id="@+id/styledPlayerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:contentDescription=""
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:use_controller="true"
                app:player_layout_id="@layout/exo_player_view"
                app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_exo_layout"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="PrivateResource" />
```

Custome_Exo_Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#80000000">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/exo_lock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:theme="@style/clickableview"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock_open"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sec_controlvid1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/exo_play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/clickableview"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/exo_icon_play" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/exo_pause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/clickableview"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/exo_icon_pause" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sec_controlvid2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/exo_position"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:text="/"
            android:textColor="#CBCDC8" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/exo_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#CBCDC8" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/exo_bt_fullScreen"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:theme="@style/clickableview"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_fullscreen" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
        android:id="@+id/exo_progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
        app:buffered_color="#95989F"
        app:played_color="#FF0000"
        app:scrubber_color="#FF0000"
        app:unplayed_color="#45424E">
     </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar>
   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    root = binding.getRoot();

  StyledPlayerView  styledPlayerView = binding.styledPlayerView;
  ExoPlayer  exoPlayer = new ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
            .build();

    styledPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
    styledPlayerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);

    exoPlayer.addListener(new Player.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaybackStateChanged(int playbackState) {
            Player.Listener.super.onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState);
          if (playbackState == Player.STATE_BUFFERING)
                progressBarVideoHomeLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else if (playbackState == Player.STATE_READY)
                progressBarVideoHomeLoader.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

    exoPlayer.addMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse(videoURL)));
    exoPlayer.prepare();
    exoPlayer.play();
  return root;
```

}

clickableview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="clickableview">
     <item name="colorControlHighlight">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
     <item name="android:background">?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In StyledPlayerView there is no two buttons to play and pause video, and you should change below codes:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@id/exo_play"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/clickableview"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/exo_icon_play" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@id/exo_pause"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/clickableview"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/exo_icon_pause" />
```

To:

```
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/exo_play_pause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/clickableview"
        style="@style/ExoStyledControls.Button.Center.PlayPause"/>
```

Comment: how to manage play pause click event

Comment: How to add custom Icon for play/pause in it

Answer (score -1):

you just have to add `android:visibility="gone"` to your `exo_pause`. Make changes in your code as below

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sec_controlvid1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/exo_play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/exo_ic_play_circle_filled"
        app:tint="@color/white"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/exo_pause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/exo_ic_pause_circle_filled"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:tint="@color/white"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

or add the below code or make changes as your requirement.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/sec_controlvid1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/exo_play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/exo_ic_play_circle_filled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/exo_pause"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/exo_pause"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/exo_pause"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/exo_pause"
        app:tint="@color/white"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/exo_pause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/exo_ic_pause_circle_filled"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tint="@color/white"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I know that you already know that don't have to change any `Exoplayer's id`.
If the problem is not solved yet, let me know